# I do not understand what this PDE problem is looking for?!

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, wave-equation

[image]

This is an exercise in Qing book. the given hint is not helping me with what the problem is looking for and how to begin. I would appreciate any help.

ps. I am studying uniqueness of solutions of PDEs. and so far I have studied a heat equation has a unique solution. so since the solution on boundary of domain is given 0, can I conclude directly u is zero at all domain?

Comment: It’s asking you to prove that $u=0$ is the unique solution to the problem.

Comment: What do you mean, you don't know what the problem is looking for? It says you should prove that $u=0$; hence "what the problem is looking for" is a proof that $u=0$... (No, that doesn't help with how to prove it. One question at a time...)

Comment: Step 1: try to prove the statement that is in the Hint, namely try to prove that $J$ is decreasing convex function for a _non-vanishing solution_ (so that $\dot{J} \leq 0$ and $\ddot{J} \geq 0$); notice that if $u\equiv 0$ technically $J$ is not well-defined (formally $-\infty$). Step 2: try to prove that if $J(t)$ is a decreasing convex function, then $J$ can never reach $-\infty$ in finite time.

Comment: thanks, but then doesnt this show u can not become zero!?

Comment: If you can show that a non-vanishing solution can't become zero, then you're done because the boundary condition $u(\cdot,T)=0$ requires $u$ to become zero.